# Easiest way to achieve this effect?

Tags: html, css, scroll, fixed

Was browing some wordpress themes and stumbled upon this one.

http://www.pixarwpthemes.com/wordpress/reborn/

It seems the mainslider images are fixed and the background moves over them but I can't seem to find exactly how it's done in the code.
Can anybody help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site uses [supersized.js](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) jquery plugin for horizontal sliding images at the background.A plugin that is very easy to implement, check out the documentation and demo files.

And uses [stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) for the vertical movement.

Comment: You can use [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) for firefox or [chrome developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to inspect the scripts or code in a web page.